# Nested IFs formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to create some conditions that tell a formula where to get its data from:

```
if (A2 > B2, row=34, row = 35)

if (C2 > E2) column = E
else if (C2 > F2) column = F
else if (C2 > G2) column = G
else if (C2 > H2) column = H
```

the formula being something simple like:

```
O21/content of cell(row, column)+O22
```

Comment: Did you try taking a look at INDIRECT()?

Comment: The problem is that I have no clue on how to embed all the nested ifs i need in the indirect function. The formula would be something like =O21/INDIRECT(IF(C2>E2,"E", IF(C2>F2, "F", IF(C2>G2, "G", "H"))),IF(A2>B2,34,35))+O22, but that doesn't work :*(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested IF Statements in Excel Formula](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035161/nested-if-statements-in-excel-formula)

Comment: the problem may be that he got the solution on its own... cus its the direct rewrite of his question... regarding to his comment  he allready got the solution (just missing the &)... so he may not have seen harun24hr's solution... and as long as i know, you dont have to accapt an answer at all

Comment: Yeah, I haven't seen any of the answers when I tried to explain what happened. Sorry, first time here.

Comment: Also wonder why I can't mark two answers as possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your need to add a "&" symbol between two if function. Try following one.

=O21/INDIRECT(IF(C2>E2,"E",IF(C2>F2,"F",IF(C2>G2,"G","H"))) & IF(A2>B2,34,35))+O22

Answer (score 0):

try it with:

```
=INDIRECT("R"&35-(A2>B2)&"C"&9-MAX((C2>E2)*4,(C2>F2)*3,(C2>G2)*2,(C2>H2)*1),)
```

no `IF` needed

leads you to:

```
=O21/INDIRECT("R"&35-(A2>B2)&"C"&9-MAX((C2>E2)*4,(C2>F2)*3,(C2>G2)*2,(C2>H2)*1),)+O22
```