Excel formula with several statements
=IF(DBDR_AllDevicesTAB!M5="Not Verified","No Nameplate Info Available”,ELSEIF(AND(NOT(DBDR_AllDevicesTAB!M5="Not Verified")),DBDR_AllDevicesTAB!M5>0,DBDR_AllDevicesTAB!M5),””)))")
I am trying to look at 1 cell and if it equals "Not verified" then I want "No Nameplate" response however if it has text other than "not verified" then I want that text in the cell. If there is no text then I want blank""

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035161/nested-if-statements-in-excel-formula
